# Run SP multiple times with varying parameter counts

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure, the main part of it is a select query that looks like this:

```
SELECT 
    Col_A, Col_B,
    Col_C, Col_D,
    ...,
FROM
    TableName
WHERE
    Col_C = 'this' OR Col_C = 'that' OR Col_C = 'Other'
```

Now what if I wanted to change the values in the `WHERE` clause and have them be populated via `@Parameter` ?  If this was an ideal situation, I could simply do:

```
WHERE Col_C = @Parameter
```

But, each time this stored procedure is run, the number of possibilities that `Col_C` could be will vary from `1 to 15` different options. I don't really think that having 15 parameters and then checking to see if each parameter has a value and then comparing that value to the column is the best idea, so I am reaching out to the community for ideas as to what I may be overlooking.

I was wondering if there was a way for me to do something along the lines of:

```
EXEC @return_value = [dbo].[BM-GetWeeklyEfficiencyInformation]
     @Start_Date = ...
     @End_Date = ...
     @ResourceGroupList = 'OPTION1 OPTION2 OPTION3 OPTION4 OPTION5 ...'

SELECT @return_value
```

Then, in the `WHERE` clause in the `SP`, compare it to `OPTION1`, then `OPTION2`, `OPTION3`, and so on.

I assume this can be done in one way or another. I just don't know how to begin.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parameterize an SQL IN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterize-an-sql-in-clause)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this  - Below query depicts how you can parameterize yours IN Clause.

```
SELECT 
       Col_A,
       Col_B,
       Col_C,
       Col_D,
       ...,
FROM
       TableName
WHERE
       Col_C in( select value from  STRING_SPLIT('this,that,Other',','))
```

*Note: STRING_SPLIT function available in SQL Server 2016 or later, if you are using below SQL server 2016 then you can write custom split function.*

Comment: I tweaked it a little bit to work with the parameter being passed: (SELECT value FROM string_split(@ResourceGroup, ',')) ... that works like a treat.  Thank you, @mukesh-arora

Answer (score 0):

If you can pass all Options with comma separated then you can use below query

```
SELECT 
       Col_A,
       Col_B,
       Col_C,
       Col_D,
       ...,
FROM
       TableName
WHERE
 ',' + 'this,that,Other' + ',' Like  '%,' + lTrim(rTrim(Col_C)) + ',%'
```

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=62a4bba3b68b1bbf523d1bae196b1aca)**